# Selected Dimension Value in Expression in QlikView

Tags: qlikview

Just wondering how to get a selected value in an expression. I have the following bar chart, with drill down from Year to months.

[image: QlikView chart Before Drill down]

When I click say 2011 bar I get the following chart.

[image: QlikView chart After Drill down]

Now is there a way to get **Transported Mail - 2011** in the second chart instead of just plain **Transported Mail**. Note that 2011 is the current selected year. I want it to be incorporated in the label expression. Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use set analysis for this...

Try this:

```
= 'Transported Mail -' & concat({state_name} DISTINCT year_var,',')
```

*Note* If you haven't created any alternate states, you can use `$` as your `state_name`

Now, you can get much more complicated with this to allow it to handle multiple years differently, but this should do the trick for you.

Comment: Perfect. It worked. The following is the expression. = 'Transported Mail -' & concat({$} DISTINCT Year,',')